# Non-stub Android Google map jar file

Tags: android, google-maps

The Google maps.jar found in android-sdk directory contains only stubs. If we check the bytecodes of the methods in each class, they all throw runtime stub exceptions.
Is it possible to get a non-stub version of maps.jar? I am using it to automatically verify android apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get it from a device. 
It will be present at `/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar` . I am not sure if you will be able to use it on emulator.